# Is bulk delete with named query a bad practice with JPA/HIBERNATE?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, eclipselink, named-query

Is a bad practice to do bulk delete with named query ?

Like this for instance:

```
DELETE FROM PERSON 
WHERE ID IN ( 
    SELECT c.person.ID 
      FROM COUNTRY c 
     WHERE COUNTRY = 'BRAZIL'
);
```

If so, why?

I know that named query do not respect the cascade and others jpa anotation that need to be solved manually, but besides that, is it a bad practice? Is there a prefered way of doing that?

Comment: This is an opinion/subjective based question, so I don't quite know what type of answers you are expecting - but your query cannot work. COUNTRY cannot have person references and still be treated as a string 'BRAZIL'.

Answer (score 1):

This type of query bypasses JPA caching mechanisms, so you are own your own if there is relationship maintenance required or involved with this entity - Country may still have stale references to deleted Person in any caches. Some JPA providers (EclipseLink) have 2 levels of caching by default, so such issues can stick around for a long time - until the Country is refreshed or the application restarted.

But every tool has its place. I've used it frequently in past projects to efficiently remove larger datasets without having to fetch it into memory just to call EntityManager.remove(entity) on it. It isn't a pattern I'd recommend overusing or going to first, but it certainly is a great tool when required.